# How do I turn Collides on so that objects stop going through each other when I'm moving a object

Tags: modeling

Let's say i wanted to make a box, but to make a box you need 6 sides. If i wanted each of them to never overlap and be perfect. Is there any way to turn collides on?

Comment: Nope, Blender 2.79 doesn't have "live" collisions.

Comment: However, is sounds as if you were trying to look for [snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#snapping).

Comment: Is this about modelling or physics simulation?